# PHP - Call to undefined function

Tags: php, ajax

i am geting a call to undefined function setChild() in a php script called by ajax, functions is declared up the call, this is the code... (Any help will be very appreciated)

```
<?php

include ( 'config.php' );

$usuarioID = $_POST[ 'UsuarioID' ];

function setChid( $liderID ) {
    $row = null;

    $connection = new mysqli( $host, $user, $password, $dataBase, $port );
    $query = 'SELECT UsuarioID, Nombre FROM Usuarios WHERE (LiderID=' . $liderID . ')';
    $result = $connection->query( $query );

    echo ( '<ul>' );

        while( $row = $result->fetch_array() ) {
            echo ( '<li>' . $row[1] . '</li>' );
        }

    echo ( '</ul>' );

    mysqli_close();
}

$row = null;

$connection = new mysqli( $host, $user, $password, $dataBase, $port );
$query = 'SELECT UsuarioID, Nombre FROM Usuarios WHERE (UsuarioID=' . $usuarioID . ')';
$result = $connection->query( $query );

while( $row = $result->fetch_array() ) {
    echo ( '<ul class="tree">' );
        echo ( '<li>' . $row[1] . '</li>' );

        setChild( $row[0] );

    echo ( '</ul>' );
}

mysqli_close();
```

?>

Comment: it is not very good to open a new mysql connection with every function call, send your connection as a variable to the function.

Comment: Your function is declared as `setChid`. You're missing an `l`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and yea very nice eye, i was reading and reading the code witout success, i'll go to correct that open mysql connection in function

Comment: another error: mysqli_close(); instead of mysqli_close( $connection );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function name is

```
function setChid( $liderID ) {
```

and calling as

```
setChild( $row[0] );
```

So you need to correct that.

So change

```
function setChid( $liderID ) {
```

to

```
function setChild( $liderID ) {
```

Comment: Nice catch, keen eye!